# Mongo Aggregate Combine Two Documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Once I've unwound a sub-document array, how do I put it back together with all the original root fields?

Consider the following **Tasks** data set:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e95bb1cf36c0ab3247036bd",
        "name": "Task A",
        "org": "5e95b9894a0aa0b30dfcbc0b",
        "creator": "5e117e5cd90de7187b000d87"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e95bb30f36c0ab3247036be",
        "name": "Task B1",
        "org": "5e95b9894a0aa0b30dfcbc0b",
        "creator": "5e117e5cd90de7187b000d87",
        "parent": "5e95bb1cf36c0ab3247036bd"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e95bb35f36c0ab3247036bf",
        "name": "Task B2",
        "org": "5e95b9894a0aa0b30dfcbc0b",
        "creator": "5e117e5cd90de7187b000d87",
        "parent": "5e95bb1cf36c0ab3247036bd"
    }
]
```

So, then I run `$graphLookup` to get the parent task and populate it's children and then $unwind it and populate the `creator` field:

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "parent": {
                "$exists": false
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$graphLookup": {
            "from": "tasks",
            "startWith": "$_id",
            "connectFromField": "_id",
            "connectToField": "parent",
            "as": "children"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$children"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "children.creator",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "children.creator"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$children.creator"
        }
    }
]
```

Which returns the following documents:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e95bb1cf36c0ab3247036bd",
        "name": "Task A",
        "org": "5e95b9894a0aa0b30dfcbc0b",
        "creator": "5e117e5cd90de7187b000d87",
        "children": [
            {
                "_id": "5e95bb30f36c0ab3247036be",
                "name": "Task B1",
                "org": "5e95b9894a0aa0b30dfcbc0b",
                "creator": {
                    "name": "Jack Frost"
                },
                "parent": "5e95bb1cf36c0ab3247036bd"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5e95bb1cf36c0ab3247036bd",
        "name": "Task A",
        "org": "5e95b9894a0aa0b30dfcbc0b",
        "creator": "5e117e5cd90de7187b000d87",
        "children": [
            {
                "_id": "5e95bb35f36c0ab3247036bf",
                "name": "Task B2",
                "org": "5e95b9894a0aa0b30dfcbc0b",
                "creator": {
                    "name": "Bill Nye"
                },
                "parent": "5e95bb1cf36c0ab3247036bd"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Lastly, I need to merge all of these duplicate documents back together and join the `$children`. This is the part I can't figure out. Below is some junk I'm trying but it seems messy to have to specifically list every property.

***Is there a better way to combine multiple (mostly) matching docs?***

```
[
    ...
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": {
                "$mergeObjects": "$properties"
            },
            "watchers": {
                "$addToSet": "$watchers"
            },
            "assignees": {
                "$addToSet": "$assignees"
            },
            "org": {
                "$addToSet": "$$ROOT.org"
            },
            "children": {
                "$push": "$children"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, the best solution I can find is to specify each property but pass it the `$first` operator. This will ensure that the original value will be passed through.

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        name: {$first: '$name'},
        org: {$first: '$org'},
        creator: {$first: '$creator'},
        children: {$push: '$children'} 
    }
}
```